# Show that $f:S=\{z\in\mathbb C:Re(z)\in[-\pi,\pi]\}\to\mathbb C:z\to e^{z}$ is bounded.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show that $f:S=\{z\in\mathbb C:Re(z)\in[-\pi,\pi]\}\to\mathbb C:z\to e^{z}$ is bounded.

**My Attempt:** $|f(x+iy)|=|e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)|=e^x$ is bounded on $\forall~ x\in[-\pi,\pi]\implies f$ is bounded on $S.$

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close to a good solution.

$S$ bounded means that there is some disc in $\mathbb{C}$ containing $S$. So you need to find some big $R$ such that $S \subset C_R$, where $C_R$ is the set $\{ z \, | \, |z| \leq R \}$

Now, as you said, $|e^z|=e^x$, where $x = \Re(z)$. Since $\Re(z) \in [-\pi,\pi]$ and since $e^x$ is strictly increasing, this implies that $|e^z|$ must lie in the interval $[e^{-\pi},e^\pi]$. So if you choose $R > e^\pi$, you see that $S$ must lie inside $C_R$.

This implies that $S$ is bounded.

Comment: Disk instead of circle.

Answer (score 2):

The complex exponential function is periodic with period $2\pi i$, so we have $f(z+2\pi i) = f(z)$ for all $z \in S$.

Then we have that $f(S) = f(S')$ where $S' = \{z \in \mathbb C \mid -\pi \leq \operatorname{Re} z \leq \pi, 0 \leq \operatorname{Im} z \leq 2\pi\}$, i.e. $f(S)$ is the continuous image of the compact set $S'$, so it is compact.